# Excel VBA : Multiple Worksheet export to multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba, export

I have an excel report with 2 sheets I need to export to separate excel files when I kick off the Macro. Currently it will only export the 1 sheet and give me an error on the second sheet, but not sure what I am doing wrong.

The 2 tabs in my workbook is "Direct Sales by Mgr Rep" and "Dealer Channel Sales by Partner"

My macro has other lines abover the below code to update tabs that flow into the final reporting tabs which are the 2 tabs i want to export each into a file.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. currently the macro runs the first export but fails on the second export.

```
'excel read only
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Direct Sales by Mgr Rep").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="MY FILE", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False

'excel read only
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Dealer Channel Sales by Partnr").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="MYFILE", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that because you are saving `ActiveWorkbook` with 1 sheet and by the time you try to do the second sheet it doesn't exist? Once you save it, you are no longer in the original workbook. You are then in the saved workbook because you are doing `SaveAs`

Comment: Specify the workbook `Sheets("Direct Sales...")` and `Sheets("Dealer Channel Sales...")` are in - `ThisWorkbook` maybe?

Comment: No need for `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` twice in here - you only need a `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end of your subroutine.